# Delete axis value for a gchart in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to do a bar plot with categories using gchart in SAS. I have in the horizontal axis dates, so I don't want that appear because looks chaotic. I'm using the following code

```
axis1 label=none value=none;                                                                                                            


axis2 label=(angle=90 'Porcentaje');                                                                                                       


legend1 label=('Categoría') frame;                                                                                                       

proc gchart data=base_fechas;                                                                                                                  
   vbar REPORTE_FCH/ discrete subgroup=TPO_SEX                                                                                             
                 group=REPORTE_FCH  g100 nozero                                                                                               
                  type=percent                                                                                                
                 inside=percent width=20                                                                                                
                 gaxis=axis1 raxis=axis2                                                                                                
                 legend=legend1;                                                                                                        
run;                                                                                                                                    
quit;
```

but the values of the axis still apear. How can I delete de values of the horizontal axis?

Comment: A wild gues `axis1;` might undo the `axis1 label=none value=none;`, just like `title;` undoes `title MyTitle;`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `vbar <date> / … group=<date> g100 … ;`

The `group=<date>` axis rendering is controlled by the `gaxis` option.  The `vbar <date>` are mid-points and their rendering are controlled by the `maxis` option.

You can hide the midpoints by specifying `vbar` option `maxis=axis1`

This example hides both the midpoints and the groups:

```
data have;

  do date = today()-100 to today();
    do index = 1 to 50 * ranuni(123);

      sex = substr('MF',1+(rannor(123) > 0.75),1);
      output;

    end;
  end;

  format date yymmdd10.;
run;

axis1 label=none value=none;
axis2 label=(angle=90 '%');

proc gchart data=have;
  vbar date
  / discrete
    subgroup = sex
    GROUP = date
    G100
    nozero
    type=percent
    inside=percent width=20

    gaxis = axis1 
    raxis = axis2
    maxis = axis1
  ;

  where date > today()-20;
run;
```